# Neural network can't seem to learn a simple relationship TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm experimenting with TensorFlow (which seems amazing so far!) and I'm playing around with a toy example a 1 class classification problem. I'm generating some features and if the first feature is above a threshold then the example is "positive"

Full code here:
https://gist.github.com/tnbredillet/f136c2bc40815517e0aa1139bd2060ee

The problem is that it seems that the model is unable to capture that simple relationship.
Of course I'm missing a lot of stuff (CV, regularization, batch normalization, hyperparameter tuning) to name a few.
But still I would expect the model to manage to figure that one out right ?
Maybe there's simply a bug in my code?

Would welcome any insights :-)

EDIT:

Data generating code:

```
num_examples = 100000
split = 0.2
num_features = 1


def generate_input_data(num_examples, num_features):
    features = []
    labels = []
    for i in xrange(num_examples):
        features.append(np.random.rand(num_features) * np.random.randint(1, 10) + np.random.rand(num_features))
    if np.random.randint(101) > 90:
        features[i-1][np.random.randint(num_features)] = 0

    hard = ceil(np.sum(features[i-1])) % 2
    easy = 0
    if features[i-1][0] > 3:
        easy = 1
    labels.append(easy)

    df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(features),
        pd.Series(labels).rename('labels')
    ],
    axis=1,
    )
    return df


def one_hot_encoding(train_df):
    #TODO: handle categorical feature one hot encoding.
    return 0, 0


def scale_data(train_df, test_df):
    categorical_columns, encoding = one_hot_encoding(train_df)

    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))

    scaler.fit(train_df.drop(['labels'], axis=1))

    train_df = pd.concat(
        [
            pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(train_df.drop('labels', axis=1))),
            train_df['labels']
        ],
        axis=1,
    )
    test_df = pd.concat(
        [
        pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(test_df.drop('labels', axis=1))),
        test_df['labels']
        ],
        axis=1,
    )

    return train_df, test_df


def preprocess_data(train_df, test_df):
    all_dfs = [train_df, test_df]
    features = set()
    for df in all_dfs:
        features |= set(df.columns)

    for df in all_dfs:
        for f in features:
            if f not in df.columns:
                df[f] = 0.0

    for df in all_dfs:
        df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)

    train_df, test_df = scale_data(train_df, test_df)


    train_df = shuffle(train_df).reset_index(drop=True)

    return train_df, test_df


def get_data(num_examples, split):
    train_df = generate_input_data(num_examples, num_features)
    test_df = generate_input_data(int(ceil(num_examples*split)), num_features)
    return preprocess_data(train_df, test_df)

def get_batch(df, batch_size, epoch):
    start = batch_size*epoch-batch_size
    end = batch_size*epoch
    if end > len(df):
        end = len(df)
    size = end - start       
    batch_x = df.drop('labels', axis=1)[start:end].as_matrix()
    batch_y = df['labels'][start:end].as_matrix().reshape(size, 1)
    return batch_x, batch_y
```

And the network definition/training and evaluation:

```
train_df, test_df = get_data(num_examples, split)

n_hidden_1 = 8
n_hidden_2 = 4
learning_rate = 0.01
batch_size = 500
num_epochs = 200
display_epoch = 50

def neural_net(x):
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_features, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, 1]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))
}

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, num_features))
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))    

logits = neural_net(X)

loss_op =         tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)

predictions = tf.sigmoid(logits)
predicted_class = tf.greater(predictions, 0.5)
correct = tf.equal(predicted_class, tf.equal(Y,1.0))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean( tf.cast(correct, 'float') )

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

    for epoch in range(1, num_epochs + 1):
        batch_x, batch_y = get_batch(train_df, batch_size, epoch)
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
        if epoch % display_epoch == 0 or epoch == 1:
            loss, acc , pred, fff= sess.run([loss_op, accuracy, predictions, logits],
                                           feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                                      Y: batch_y})
            c = ', '.join('{}={}'.format(*t) for t in zip(pred, batch_y))
            print("[{}] Batch loss={:.4f}, Accuracy={:.5f}, Logits vs labels= {}".format(epoch, loss, acc, c))


    print("Optimization Finished!")

    batch_x, batch_y = get_batch(test_df, batch_size, 1)
    print("Testing Accuracy:", \
    sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: batch_x,
                                  Y: batch_y}))
```

final output:

```
[1] Batch loss=3.2160, Accuracy=0.41000
[50] Batch loss=0.6661, Accuracy=0.61800
[100] Batch loss=0.6472, Accuracy=0.65200
[150] Batch loss=0.6538, Accuracy=0.64000
[200] Batch loss=0.6508, Accuracy=0.64400
Optimization Finished!
('Testing Accuracy:', 0.63999999)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it is not a machine learning algorithm problem, but a bug in your data generation which is scrambling the relationship that you intend. In this function:

```
def generate_input_data(num_examples, num_features):
    features = []
    labels = []
    for i in xrange(num_examples):
        features.append(np.random.rand(num_features) * np.random.randint(1, 10) + np.random.rand(num_features))
    if np.random.randint(101) > 90:
        features[i-1][np.random.randint(num_features)] = 0

    hard = ceil(np.sum(features[i-1])) % 2
    easy = 0
    if features[i-1][0] > 3:
        easy = 1
    labels.append(easy)

    df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(features),
        pd.Series(labels).rename('labels')
    ],
    axis=1,
    )
    return df
```

You are indexing features by `i-1` to determine the label. However, `xrange` will generate numbers starting from `0`, so you don't need to subtract the `1`. In fact, when you do, the relationship becomes close to random, and essentially unpredictable, so even though the rest of your model is OK, it won't be able to score well.

So you need to index by `i` instead e.g. `if features[i][0] > 3`.